# PHP exec returns "array" instead of the result of my command

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to build a web terminal emulator on my local webserver (openwrt), every time I execute the command, the result always says "array", for instance when I execute `uptime` it doesn't give me the up time of my webserver but instead it gives me `array`. This is my script:

```
<?php
..............................
if($_POST['command'])
{
$command = $_POST['command'];
exec("$command 2>&1 &", $output);
echo $command;
}
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
echo "Command:<br><input type=\"text\" autofocus name=\"command\" size=\"15\" value=\"\"/><br>";
echo '<br>Result :<br><pre>
        <div id="show" style="font-size: 11px;  word-wrap: break-word; width:550px;height:200px;border:0px solid #000;text-align:left; overflow-y: scroll;">
        '.$output.'</div>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="kill" value="Kill Command" />';
echo "</form></div>";
.........................
?>
```

I want the `$output` to return the result of my command.
Right now, the `$output` always returns `array` no matter what type of command I execute, how should I fix this?

Comment: do print_r($command)..it may possible it comes in array format

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)? "If the output argument is present, then the specified **array** will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this **array**." Use `print_r` or `var_dump` to print arrays.

Comment: Why don't people read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is supposed to return an array as it is written in the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

If you want to print the array line by line use a code like this:

```
<?php
exec("$command 2>&1 &", $output);
foreach ($output as $line) {
    echo "$line\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** You can use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to combine the array result to a string.

```php
exec("$command 2>&1 &", $output);
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $output);
```

**Option 2:** You can use [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) which return the complete output as a string.

```php
echo shell_exec("$command 2>&1 &");
```